# C# - Writing to file with filestream

Tags: c#, .net

Is this the correct way of using Filestream?
If so, is there anything i can improve in this function?
Its mainly planned, to be used to write to an ftp-folder, containing 600+ lines of data.

My concern is the for loop.

This is my first time using C# for work. So i can use the advice.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//FINISH BUTTON
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePathBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileNameBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please check folderpath or filename.", 
                    "WARNING");
            }
            else
            {
                String vFullPath = FilePathBox.Text + "/" + FileNameBox.Text + ExtentionBox.Text;
                MainProgressBar.Maximum = OutputBox.Items.Count;

                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(vFullPath))
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < OutputBox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //String vInput = OutputBox.Items[i].ToString() + "\n";
                        //File.AppendAllText(vFullPath, vInput);
                        String vInput = OutputBox.Items[i].ToString() + "\n";
                        byte[] vData = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(vInput);
                        fs.Write(vData, 0, vData.Length);
                        MainProgressBar.Value = i;
                    }
                }

                MainProgressBar.Value = MainProgressBar.Maximum;
                MessageBox.Show("Finished Writing to file.",
                    "Completed");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not too bad for a beginner. You might want to _not_ do File I/O on the Event Dispatch Thread. So, may consider making the event hander `async void` and start and await a Task to which you move all the File I/O. Then your App stays responsive. The rest is details. E.g. you don't need to create a new Encoding instance in each iteration ... but one step at a time.

Comment: You also may want to consider renaming the button (and all the event handlers) to something meaningful instead of "button3".

Comment: @Fildor, thanks for the advice! ill look into the async way a bit more. Do you maybe have a visual example? Or some docs that i can look into?

Comment: I'd actually recommend to just search some of the terms like "async task" together with "C#" on youtube and surely, you'll get a bunch of tutorial videos, for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more typical approach would be to wrap the stream in a StreamWriter, this has [write methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=net-6.0) for strings , removing the need to convert everything to bytes. You can select the encoding in the constructor. There is also a BinaryWriter for writing binary data.

Writing data in a loop is not a problem. You could perhaps create a complete string in memory with `String.Join` instead, and use `File.WriteAllLines`, but I would not expect very much to be gained.

My preferred method for reporting progress is to run the work on a background thread using `Task.Run`, set a property describing the progress in a shared object, and create a timer on the UI thread that polls said property and updates the progress-bar. That helps ensure the UI is responsive.

I would also consider using some kind of serialization library, like [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). This greatly simplifies the process of turning a object into a file and back again. But it is less relevant for things like logging.

Comment: Just would like to add: For reporting progress, there is [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-6.0), which is awesome.